# Is there a way to prevent a cursor from being clicked on a certain string?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, mouseevent

I'm trying to make it so that when I click on a certain string, the blinking cursor won't be placed there. Sort of like the working directory display in command line interfaces.
I was thinking that I could

- first, get the pixel width and height of the text
- then, I could find a way to block mouse events from reaching that part of a component (e.g. activate the glass pane)

The problem is, the text is in a TextArea, so I would have to override the TextAreas MouseEvent listeners.

It seems like there's a better, less hacky, solution for this. I'd prefer answers in JavaFX, but if that isn't possible, a Swing answer will be okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following solution and see if it fits.  What it does is override the `positionCaret` method from `TextArea` and prevent it from doing anything if the user has clicked inside a blocked range.  In the sample, the blocked text that the user cannot position the caret inside is the "Lorem Ipsum: " prefix on each line.

[image: sample]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public class InputBlocker extends Application {
    private static final String TEXT =
            "Lorem ipsum: dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla in nisi sed neque porttitor volutpat. \n" +
            "\n" +
            "Lorem ipsum: Maecenas non mauris scelerisque, egestas felis quis, venenatis risus. Etiam eu ornare justo, at pulvinar tortor. ";

    private static final String FORBIDDEN_PREFIX = "Lorem ipsum: ";

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
        TextArea textArea = new BlockingTextArea(TEXT, FORBIDDEN_PREFIX);
        textArea.setWrapText(true);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(textArea));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        launch(args);
    }
}

class BlockingTextArea extends TextArea {
    private final String forbiddenPrefix;
    private List<Range> blockedRanges;

    public BlockingTextArea(String text, String forbiddenPrefix) {
        super(text);

        this.forbiddenPrefix = forbiddenPrefix;
        this.blockedRanges = findBlockedRanges(text);

        textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
                blockedRanges = findBlockedRanges(newValue)
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void positionCaret(int pos) {
        Optional<Range> blockedRange =
                blockedRanges.stream()
                        .filter(range -> range.containsExclusive(pos))
                        .findFirst();

        if (blockedRange.isPresent()) {
            return;
        }

        super.positionCaret(pos);
    }

    private List<Range> findBlockedRanges(String text) {
        List<Range> blocked = new ArrayList<>();

        int idx = 0;
        while (idx < text.length()) {
            if (text.startsWith(forbiddenPrefix, idx)) {
                blocked.add(new Range(idx, idx + forbiddenPrefix.length()));
                idx += forbiddenPrefix.length();
            }

            int nextIdx = text.indexOf("\n", idx);
            if (nextIdx == -1) {
                break;
            }

            idx = nextIdx + 1;
        }

        return blocked;
    }

    private class Range {
        private final int min;
        private final int max;

        Range(int min, int max) {
            this.min = min;
            this.max = max;
        }

        public int getMin() {
            return min;
        }

        public int getMax() {
            return max;
        }

        boolean containsExclusive(int pos) {
            return min <= pos && pos < max;
        }
    }
}
```

The above solution suffers from some usability issues:

- The user can still position the character after the blocked text, then backspace to delete into the blocked text area.  Perhaps overriding `replaceText` or `deleteText` might help address that.
- Drag and click selections that pass through blocked text areas go a little wonky as they rely on caret positioning.  Perhaps overriding `selectPositionCaret` or `selectRange` or some other method might help address that.

But anyway, perhaps the above code can give you some example of how you might approach the issue and solve your problem.

Rather than a TextArea, the third party [RichTextFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX) might be a better candidate control to use for this kind of application as it allows styling of text contents that may allow for a better user experience in which text which the caret cannot be positioned is styled in different way from the rest of the text. I haven't done any investigation on how the caret blocking functionality would be implemented for RichTextFX.